# Exclude products from list.phtml results (magento)

Tags: php, magento

Is there a way forcibly exclude items (by an attribute value) from the list.phtml view in Magento? 
We have products that should be cartable, viewable individually but should not be found via searching or navigating to their category.

Comment: Why to add them to category then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We ended up figuring this out without creating a new module. We created an override to list.php in /app/code/local/mage/catalog/block/product and included the following lines of code:

```
$collection->clear()
->addAttributeToFilter('my_attribute_name', array('gteq'=> 524 )) //custom attrib ID
->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', array('eq'=> 4 )) // Visibility is equal to "Catalog/Search"
->load();
```

Just after:

```
protected function _beforeToHtml()
{
    $toolbar = $this->getToolbarBlock();

    // called prepare sortable parameters
    $collection = $this->_getProductCollection();

    // use sortable parameters
    if ($orders = $this->getAvailableOrders()) {
        $toolbar->setAvailableOrders($orders);
    }
    if ($sort = $this->getSortBy()) {
        $toolbar->setDefaultOrder($sort);
    }
    if ($dir = $this->getDefaultDirection()) {
        $toolbar->setDefaultDirection($dir);
    }
    if ($modes = $this->getModes()) {
        $toolbar->setModes($modes);
    }
```

And before:

```
// set collection to toolbar and apply sort
```

We also added this same logic to new.php for a new products page so it would filter out products that shouldn't be visible.

Brad

Answer (score 2):

You can extend the `getProductCollection` method of the `Mage_Catalog_Model_Category` (and then create a custom Block class to replace certain templates, if you like).

Assume, this is done within a module called `<YourNamespace>_<YourModule>`, this would look like:

```
class <YourNamespace>_<YourModule>_Model_Category extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Category {
    public function getProductCollection() {
        $collection = parent::getProductCollection()
        foreach($collection as $key => $item) {
            if (<YOUR_REMOVE_CRITERIA_HERE>) {
                $collection->removeItemByKey($key);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`<YOUR_REMOVE_CRITERIA_HERE>` can be anything from a config option to an attribute on the item (product) in the collection.

Easier solution would be to just remove them from the category, if you want a product only not to be listed in the category product listing.

Hope I could help,

lg,

flo

Comment: Easier solution would be to just remove them from the category, if you want a product only not to be listed in the category product listing. Yup that the obvious solution :)

Comment: Can you walk me through the steps of extending and creating a custom class ? Or point me in the direction of another resource that steps you through this?

Comment: a custom module tutorial can be found here: `http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/custom_module_with_custom_database_table`

Comment: I am trying to avoid creating a custom module... So, I'm trying the following in my list.phtml:

$_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection(); $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output'); $_productCollection->addAttributeToSelect(array('status', 'visibility', 'web_availability')); $_productCollection->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1); $_productCollection->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', 4); $_productCollection->addAttributeToFilter('web_availability', array('gteq' => 524)); 

But the results are not filtering by the web_availability. 
Is there some syntax I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

I know is not good practice to add business logic at the presentation layer but anyway a quick way lo limit the product list at app\design\frontend\iln\default\template\catalog\product\list.php

```
<?php $_selling_type = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('selling_type')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product); ?>

if ($_selling_type == 'No Price') 
{
  echo ('what ever you want');
}
```